# Hosting video for a WordPress site in a Docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a WordPress site which runs in a Docker container behind an nginx proxy container. I need to embed a small number of videos in the site, which total around 8GB. I looked into hosting them on Vimeo, but the site is part of a small academic project and we currently do not have the funding for an ongoing Vimeo subscription. So I have been researching the possibility of self-hosting the videos.

My intial thought was to bundle the videos into their own Docker container, and stream from there. I found [this Docker container](https://github.com/Eyevinn/docker-toolbelt) through Googling 'Docker streaming server', but I really have no idea if it represents a potential solution. I assume that we would indeed need some kind of server to stream the videos, and if so what kind of server? FFmpeg? Something like [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/ffserver/)?

Comment: if the videos are progressive mp4/webm then you can host them the same as any other web assets and just reference them via their URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to build up an extra container for the videos.

just upload them in a subdirectory of your WordPress instance. 
you can use a video plugin for embedded videos:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-video-player/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-video-plugin/

or simply use the HTML5 video tag to link the source:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: Thank you. It looks like we'll do exactly that.